# How to download Selenium for python?

Tags: python, selenium, download, module

I've been trying to download Selenium, but whenever I go into my cmd and type 'pip instal', it says: " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

When I type 'python,' it also says the same thing. How do I download selenium if it doesn't recognize pip, is there a way to manually download it?

I have python 3.5.1

Comment: Which distro you have?

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: `pip` and `python` are either not installed, or they're installed but not in your `PATH` environment variable, so the OS can't find them.

Comment: I'm on windows and I have python downloaded. my path is C:\Users\adamr>

Answer (score 0):

1. when you type python, it should take you to the python interpreter starting with >>

if it doesn't, check your python installation depending on your operatign system.

2.install pip for python
3.then simply run pip install selenium (in your question you wrote "pip instal") may be its a typo though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux or a MAC

```
$ pip install selenium
```

For windows, that would be

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium
```